# Function for subnet mask

Tags: javascript, jquery, subnet

I have a subnet mask as a value in an object. It comes in the long form, ie. 255.255.255.0 (for /24).

I haven't come across some sort of JavaScript function for calculating this. So before I write a whole lot of `if` and `else if` statements, I want to quickly double check to make sure that I didn't miss out on some JavaScript goody that does this already.

Thanks!

**Edit:**
Clarification

I was wondering if there is a JavaScript function that I don't know of, that will translate the long form and return a short form, slash notation. For Example:

If I pass `var obj_mask = "255.255.255.0";` to a existing JavaScript (API?), it will return a `/24` value.

If such function doesn't exist in JavaScript, it's fine, I have already written half the `if` statements, and I'll be happy to share it after so no one else has to write it out. But seeing that I'm new to JS, I wanted to know if such function/API existed natively to the language.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Are you saying you have a subnet mask in string form and want to turn it into binary/integer form?

Comment: Added to clarification, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just finished writing it, and then realized that it would look cleaner with `switch case`:

For anyone's reference. If there is in fact some JS function or API that will make this a lot cleaner and simpler, please answer and I'll mark it.

```
    switch(ret_mask = path.mask) {
        case "0.0.0.0":
            return ret_mask = "/0";
        case "128.0.0.0":
            return ret_mask = "/1";
        case "192.0.0.0":
            return ret_mask = "/2";
        case "224.0.0.0":
            return ret_mask = "/3";
        case "240.0.0.0":
            return ret_mask = "/4";
        case "248.0.0.0":
            return ret_mask = "/5";
        case "252.0.0.0":
            return ret_mask = "/6";
        case "254.0.0.0":
            return ret_mask = "/7";
        case "255.0.0.0":
            return ret_mask = "/8";
        case "255.128.0.0":
            return ret_mask = "/9";
        case "255.192.0.0":
            return ret_mask = "/10";
        case "255.224.0.0":
            return ret_mask = "/11";
        case "255.240.0.0":
            return ret_mask = "/12";
        case "255.248.0.0":
            return ret_mask = "/13";
        case "255.252.0.0":
            return ret_mask = "/14";
        case "255.254.0.0":
            return ret_mask = "/15";
        case "255.255.0.0":
            return ret_mask = "/16";
        case "255.255.128.0":
            return ret_mask = "/17";
        case "255.255.192.0":
            return ret_mask = "/18";
        case "255.255.224.0":
            return ret_mask = "/19";
        case "255.255.240.0":
            return ret_mask = "/20";
        case "255.255.248.0":
            return ret_mask = "/21";
        case "255.255.252.0":
            return ret_mask = "/22";
        case "255.255.254.0":
            return ret_mask = "/23";
        case "255.255.255.0":
            return ret_mask = "/24";
        case "255.255.255.128":
            return ret_mask = "/25";
        case "255.255.255.192":
            return ret_mask = "/26";
        case "255.255.255.224":
            return ret_mask = "/27";
        case "255.255.255.240":
            return ret_mask = "/28";
        case "255.255.255.248":
            return ret_mask = "/29";
        case "255.255.255.252":
            return ret_mask = "/30";
        case "255.255.255.254":
            return ret_mask = "/31";
        case "255.255.255.255":
            return ret_mask = ""
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

I use the following functions for netmask to CIDR and CIDR to netmask conversions:

```
var netmask2CIDR = (netmask) => (netmask.split('.').map(Number)
      .map(part => (part >>> 0).toString(2))
      .join('')).split('1').length -1;

var CIDR2netmask = (bitCount) => {
  var mask=[];
  for(var i=0;i<4;i++) {
    var n = Math.min(bitCount, 8);
    mask.push(256 - Math.pow(2, 8-n));
    bitCount -= n;
  }
  return mask.join('.');
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is my favorite.

Comment: Why do you use .map(Number) ??  It works the same without it

Answer (score 1):

Try ...

```
/* dotted-quad IP to integer */
function IPv4_dotquadA_to_intA( strbits ) {
    var split = strbits.split( '.', 4 );
    var myInt = (
        parseFloat( split[0] * 16777216 )   /* 2^24 */
      + parseFloat( split[1] * 65536 )      /* 2^16 */
      + parseFloat( split[2] * 256 )        /* 2^8  */
      + parseFloat( split[3] )
    );
    return myInt;
}

/* integer IP to dotted-quad */
function IPv4_intA_to_dotquadA( strnum ) {
    var byte1 = ( strnum >>> 24 );
    var byte2 = ( strnum >>> 16 ) & 255;
    var byte3 = ( strnum >>>  8 ) & 255;
    var byte4 = strnum & 255;
    return ( byte1 + '.' + byte2 + '.' + byte3 + '.' + byte4 );
}
```

Comment: That's pretty neat. Whole lot of math. It should be returning a `/24` instead, using flash notation from `255.255.255.0`.

Answer (score 1):

to be use like this subnet2Mask('255.255.0.0') and return 16

mask2Subnet(17) will return '255.255.128.0'

have fun

```
function subnet2Mask(subnet) {
  return subnet
    .split('.')
    .reduce((nbb, byte) => (
      [...Array(8).reverse().keys()]
        .reduce((nb, i) => (nb + ((byte >> i) & 1)), nbb)), 0)
}


function mask2Subnet(val) {
  return [255, 255, 255, 255]
    .map(() => [...Array(8).keys()]
      .reduce((rst) => (rst * 2 + (val-- > 0)), 0))
    .join('.')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I post here my solution for this type of problem. It can be optimized, however I leave it raw for a better readability.

```
    /** Convert number to address (dec) => split 
     * @param {Int}   Number
     * @return {Array} Array of 4 number
     */

     function num2Addr(number) {
           let binary = (''.padStart(32-number, '0')).padStart(32, '1'); // Create binary
           let addr = [];
           for(let i=0; i<4; i++) {
              let gBin = binary.slice(i*8, i*8+8); // Split block binary 8bit
              addr.push(parseInt(gBin,2)); // Bin to Number
           }
        return addr; // Return array of number
      }
     
    /** Convert address to dec => merge
     * @param  {Array} Address Number bit
     * @return {int}   Number
     */

     function addr2Num(addr) {
          let binary = '';
          addr.map( bit=> { binary += Number(bit).toString(2) } )
          let dec = binary.split('1').length - 1; 
           return dec;
        }
        
    // Check 
    for (let i=0; i<33; i++) {
        console.log(i, num2Addr(i) ) ;
        console.log(i, addr2Num( num2Addr(i) )  ) ;
    }

/**
Output : 
0 [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
0 0
1 [ 128, 0, 0, 0 ]
1 1
2 [ 192, 0, 0, 0 ]
2 2
3 [ 224, 0, 0, 0 ]
3 3
4 [ 240, 0, 0, 0 ]
4 4
5 [ 248, 0, 0, 0 ]
5 5
6 [ 252, 0, 0, 0 ]
6 6
7 [ 254, 0, 0, 0 ]
7 7
8 [ 255, 0, 0, 0 ]
8 8
9 [ 255, 128, 0, 0 ]
9 9
10 [ 255, 192, 0, 0 ]
10 10
11 [ 255, 224, 0, 0 ]
11 11
12 [ 255, 240, 0, 0 ]
12 12
13 [ 255, 248, 0, 0 ]
13 13
14 [ 255, 252, 0, 0 ]
14 14
15 [ 255, 254, 0, 0 ]
15 15
16 [ 255, 255, 0, 0 ]
16 16
17 [ 255, 255, 128, 0 ]
17 17
18 [ 255, 255, 192, 0 ]
18 18
19 [ 255, 255, 224, 0 ]
19 19
20 [ 255, 255, 240, 0 ]
20 20
21 [ 255, 255, 248, 0 ]
21 21
22 [ 255, 255, 252, 0 ]
22 22
23 [ 255, 255, 254, 0 ]
23 23
24 [ 255, 255, 255, 0 ]
24 24
25 [ 255, 255, 255, 128 ]
25 25
26 [ 255, 255, 255, 192 ]
26 26
27 [ 255, 255, 255, 224 ]
27 27
28 [ 255, 255, 255, 240 ]
28 28
29 [ 255, 255, 255, 248 ]
29 29
30 [ 255, 255, 255, 252 ]
30 30
31 [ 255, 255, 255, 254 ]
31 31
32 [ 255, 255, 255, 255 ]
32 32
*/
```